# Matlab Vs Python: Slicing

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I am trying to covert some Matlab code to Python. I am having problems with slicing.

Matlab Code:

```
demod_1_b=-1*mod_noisy*2.*sin(2*pi*Fc*t+phi);
y = filter(Hd,demod_1_b);
y2=conv(y,raised)/ConvFac;
%% till this line the length in python and Matlab are same
y2=y2(sa/2:end-(sa/2));
%%%% when i write this line in Python it gives me wrong answer it should come out as   26     but in python it gives me 33 i think i havnt converted it in a rigth way 
demod_3_b=y2(sa/2:sa:end);
```

Python Code:

```
demod_1_b=-1*mod_noisy*2*sin((2*pi*Fc*t)+phi)

N=10
Fc=40
Fs=1600
d=firwin(numtaps=N,cutoff=40,nyq=Fs/2)
print(len(d))
Hd=lfilter( d, 1.0, demod_1_b)
y2=(convolve(Hd,raised))/Convfac
print(len(y2))
y2=y2[(sa/2)-1:-sa/2]
print(len(y2))
 # problem starts here
demod_3_b=y2[(sa/2)-1:sa:,]
print(len(demod_3_a))
```

I just want ask, are `demod_3_b=y2(sa/2:sa:end);` in Matlab and `demod_3_v=y2[(sa/2)-1:sa:,]` in Python the same?

Comment: sorry cant post the entire code its very huge

Comment: What are you even trying to do? Can you trim the code down to a short, self-contained, runnable snippet that demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your indexing is wrong. In NumPy, the following [indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) applies:

> The basic slice syntax is i:j:k where i is the starting index, j is the stopping index, and k is the step (k≠0).

Hence, what you are looking for in Python is:

```
y2[(sa/2)-1::sa]
```

Unlike in Matlab, the stepsize is the last input. As you want to process the entire length of your array, don't put anything between the two `:`.

Comment: thaks it was helpfull indeed